Turkey Breast cooking unevenly
I took out the turkey when the deepest part of the breast reached 152F. However probing closer to the surface of the turkey, I was getting measurements around 175F. The turkey breast did not taste that moist to me and it's likely because most of the breast was overcooked.
Is the large temperature difference normal when cooking turkey or did I do something wrong?
Would improper defrost lead to a 23F temperature difference? If not, what are ways I can avoid the uneven cooking of the breast? Does it help if I flip the bird over and rotate the pan around to get more even cooking? Does spatchcocking help? Should I try cooking low and slow at 250F vs 350F? Is the only way to get more evenly cooked turkey breast by sous vide?

related, maybe duplicate? https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/102645/tips-on-cooking-fish-meat-when-not-even-thickness

cooking at a lower temperature will always minimize the temperature differential between the surface and center
